# Regarding Type Error: TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Period'

Tags: python, pandas, duration, quantlib

I am a financial analyst and a begginer of Python. I received the following Error message and could not solve it. What I would like to do is to calculate 433 JGB bond durations line by line of the matrix data. I would be very happy if someone would give me an advice to cope with this error.

```
url = "https://github.com/nagamamo/JGB/blob/main/JGB2year.csv?raw=true
df = pd.read_csv(url)
for data in df.itertuples():
  n = df['days']
  c = df['c']
  r = df['r']
  N = df['N']
  start = ql.Date().todaysDate
  maturity = start + ql.Period(n, ql.Days)
  bond = ql.FixedRateBond(2, ql.TARGET(), N, start, maturity, ql.Period('1Y'), [c], ql.ActualActual())
  rate = ql.InterestRate(r, ql.ActualActual(), ql.Compounded, ql.Annual)
  mod_duration = ql.BondFunctions.duration(bond, rate, ql.Duration.Modified)
```

--Error Message--

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-827e8eb02636> in <module>()
      5   N = df['N']
      6   start = ql.Date().todaysDate
----> 7   maturity = start + ql.Period(n, ql.Days)

TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Period'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    Period::Period()
    Period::Period(Integer,TimeUnit)
    Period::Period(Frequency)
    Period::Period(std::string const &)
```

Comment: What is `n`?  May you check that it's an integer?  It's possible that `pd.read_csv` is reading it as a string instead.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt and useful advice, @Luigi Ballbio. Here, I define that "n" is the maturity period (days). Reflecting the advice, I replace "n" to "730" as all the JGB bond maturity is 2 year (730 days) bond, but failed again.

 maturity = start + ql.Period(730, ql.Days)

----> 7   maturity = start + ql.Period(730, ql.Days)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'Period'

If it is not inconvenient, further comment would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're missing the final brackets in `ql.Date().todaysDate()` — it is a method so you need to call it.  Without those, you're setting `start` as the method, not its result.

Comment: Thank you again, @Luigi Ballabio. While I am currently on the train, I will do as you have suggested immediately when I return to my office. Thank you, indeed!